# JBPM/Keycloak integrated environment, Task List is not given when requested via Workbench

Tags: keycloak, jbpm

I integrated SSO througn Keycloak for JBPM 7.17 on Wildfly following the Keycloak and JBPM documentation. The processes definitions, process instances etc can be listed both via JBPM workbench and REST calls (via Postman). But when task list is requested via workbench it always is empty and when requested via REST, the task list is given.

I checked the taskevent table and it shows the processId in the userId field. But in the peopleassignments_potowners table it shows the correct userId in the entity_I'd field. I guess this is the reason for this but cannot figure out how this could happen and how to fix it. Refer below for taskevent table sample records.

```
id      logTime              pricessInstanceId  taskId  type                                                    
1277    2019-07-05 15:24:48     483 375 ADDED   
userId                                 OPTLOCK  workItemId
VMMigration.VMValidationAutomation  0   3291
1276    2019-07-05 14:15:32     482 374 ADDED   VMMigration.VMValidationAutomation  0   3290
1275    2019-07-05 14:03:38     481 373 ADDED   VMMigration.VMValidationAutomation  0   3289
1274    2019-07-05 10:29:36     480 372 ADDED   VMMigration.VMValidationAutomation  0   3288
1273    2019-07-05 09:00:26     479 371 ADDED   VMMigration.VMValidationAutomation  0   3287
1272    2019-05-31 13:27:35     476 363 COMPLETED   krisv   0   3277
1271    2019-05-31 13:27:34 Task output data updated    476 363 UPDATED krisv   0   3277
```

I should be able to see the task list via workbench. But I'm always getting an empty list.

Comment: For the first 5 records of taskevent table above, the userId is shown as "VMMigration.VMValidationAutomation" which is the processId.

Comment: I have the same problem... have you found something to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Create a role named "Administrators" on Keycloak server and assign that role to specified user.

After that tasks will be visible to that user. Because business administrators can view and manage all user tasks from the Tasks page in Business Central, located under Menu → Manage → Tasks

Reference : [JBPM TASK MANAGEMENT](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_process_automation_manager/7.5/html/managing_and_monitoring_business_processes_in_business_central/manage-tasks-con-managing-and-monitoring-processes)